# Can't echo a variable, but i can use and echo other strings

Tags: php, post, echo

Hello i post a variable to this script..
i can use the variable to make a dir, and i can echo Hola in the browser, but echo "$data" doesn't work

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['gen_id'];
system("mkdir $data");
echo "Hola";
echo "$data";
?>
```

Comment: Have you tried echo $data; ?

Comment: I'd need much more conclusive proof than that. It should work fine by all the laws of PHP and general computing. Something in the way you're *testing* is off.

Comment: BTW, PHP has a native [`mkdir` function](http://php.net/mkdir).

Comment: What do you get if you try `echo '<xmp>';var_dump($data);echo '</xmp>';` ?

Comment: i came home and test in my notebook, first post was from my lab...

Comment: i run the comand and i get Notice: Undefined index: gen_id in /var/www/SChip/test.php on line 2
Hola
NULL       but the dir is created, wtf is going on

Comment: Are you sure the directory wasn't already created by an earlier script, that might be why it's puzzling? -- it seems to me that you aren't sending the data into your script correctly... are you sure you are posting rather than getting? i.e. if you are sending your values like `?gen_id=something` then you should be using `$_GET`.. you can fallback to `$_REQUEST` to make certain (as this includes both GET and POST values), but it's best to use either `$_POST` or `$_GET` if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Echo doesn't actually echo anything (at least it appears to not to) if the string is an empty string or null. If you want to know if it's working or not use var_dump($data). When that runs it'll put on the type and show something even if it's an empty string of null.

Comment: i came home and test in my notebook, first post was from my lab...     <?php
    $data = $_POST['gen_id'];
    system("mkdir $data");
    echo "Hola";
    echo $data;
    echo '<xmp>';var_dump($data);echo '</xmp>';
    ?>
Notice: Undefined index: gen_id in /var/www/SChip/test.php on line 2
Hola
NULL

Answer (score 2):

More likely than not, your `$_POST` variable isn't set.  Try doing this, and see what you see:

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';
```

Comment: Won't you run into the same problem if print_r is truly uneset?

Comment: @IanOverton "_if print_r is unset_"?  What do you mean?  `$_POST` is always available, though possibly (and most likely in this case) empty.

Comment: It isn't set if it's a cron job or something at least I don't think it is, but your right if it's empty it would work. Your solution will work 90% of the time I just thought I'd point that out.

Comment: +1 @Madbreaks Ian Overton was, I think, stating that `print_r` isn't as accurate as `var_dump` and wont display empty values.. also it is prob. better to use `<xmp>` rather than `<pre>` in this situation as pre will allow some tags to function i.e. `<b>` *(and thusly seemingly disappear)*, whereas xmp will only ever render the exact mark-up... of course `header('content-type: text/plain');` is probably the best solution, however it's more confusing for new coders -- but then again it's probably all down to personal preference anyway ;)

Answer (score -1):

your `$_POST` variable isn't set

Comment: Adding the quotes, while not required in any way, won't _prevent_ the variable `$data` from being echoed.